# ajax script works only for the first row when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, ajax, document, ready

I have a problem my script. It purpose is to display some values in fields depending on value from dropdown select.
When I fire other scripts that are adding or removing new rows into the form with the same fields, but different row id it stops working for the newly added rows.

```
<script>
<?php echo 'var lista = '.form_dropdown('produkt[]',$lista).';'?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="produkt[]"]').change(function() {
        var id = $('select[name="produkt[]"] option:selected').val();
        var par = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        $.getJSON(
            '<?php echo $head['site_link'];?>index.php/faktura/pobierzProdukt/'+id,
            function(data){
                var id = $('#'+par);
                $('input[name="pkwiu[]"]',id).val(data.product_pkwiu);
                $('input[name="netto[]"]',id).val(data.product_netto);
                $('input[name="vat[]"]',id).val(data.product_vat);
                $('input[name="brutto[]"]',id).val(data.product_brutto);
                $('input[name="jedn[]"]',id).val(data.product_jedn);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });

    $('#dodajWiersz').click(function() {
        var liczba = $('#produkty tr').length;
        var inputArray = [
            '1',
            lista,
            '<input type="text" name="pkwiu[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="netto[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="vat[]" class="mini" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="brutto[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="jedn[]" class="mini" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="ilosc[]" class="short"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="knetto[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="kvat[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>',
            '<input type="text" name="kbrutto[]" class="short" readonly="readonly"/>'
        ];
        var tdString = '<td>'+inputArray.join('</td><td>')+'</td>';
        if($('#produkty tbody tr').length>0) {
            var row = '<tr id="wiersz-'+liczba+'">'+tdString+'</tr>';
            $('#produkty').find('tbody').append(row);
            $('#produkty tr:last td:first-child').text(liczba);
        }
        else {
            var row = '<tr id="wiersz-1">'+tdString+'</tr>';
            $('#produkty').find('tbody').append(row);
        }
    });

    $('#usunWiersz').click(function() {
       $('#produkty').find('tbody tr:last').remove(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

I think the problem is with $(document).ready() function. But I can't solve it.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that DOM is not updated. I can see the new HTML structure in Firebug but in the source view is the old structure. I think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).closest('tr').attr('id') you might always have the same id

and

var row = ''+tdString+'';

you are always appending the same id.

Comment: var row works correctly, but maybe you're right about $(this).closest()..... I'll check it out.

UPDATE:
it works correctly too

Comment: I changed the code a little. I replaced change() and click() functions with live() ones. It seems to work a little, but I can't make it work for all rows except the first one. Other rows get values from the first row's select menu.

Comment: problem is with URL which doesn't change. How can I make it null when getJSON returns data?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to change: `var id = $('select[name="produkt[]"] option:selected').val();` into `var id = $(this).val();`
It seemed to be a problem with option:selected.